# How do i get my video.mp4 to display on website?

Tags: html5-video, mp4, video-upload

I have trouble displaying a video on my website. It's working when I try it with vs code live server but not when uploaded... The video is supposed to start when you arrive on page and loop. There is also text displaying in front of video.

Html:

```
 <div class="container">
      <video autoplay loop muted>
        <source
          src="/Steak - 16395.mp4"
          type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'
        />
      </video>

      <div class="text-box">
        <h1>LINNÈA</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Css

```
.container {
width: 100%;
height: 100vh;
position: relative;
pointer-events: none;
}

.container video{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.text-box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left:0;
  background: #111;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: 900;
  mix-blend-mode:color-dodge ;
}
```

Website is uploaded with filezilla on https://www.infinityfree.net/.
Everything seems fine except the video.... Any clues?

I tried changing video format to see if that was the problem, but nothing happened.

Seperated html code from index and ran with styling in new vs code project to see if other html or styling was interfering with the video.

Tried changing browsers. (website works best with crome or edge)

Comment: _"I have trouble displaying a video on my website."_ .... Do you have a link to a test page on your website? No one can advise about a problem they can't see. A quick advice... **(1)** Try using the actual **full** path to the MP4 file (starting with a `https://`). **(2)** Don't uses spaces in your filenames (maybe use underscore like `a_new_file_name` etc if you need separations).  **(3)** Make sure your **codecs** setting is correct for your video file... finally also your browser's Developer Tools to make sure there is no problem shown in Console like "file not found".

Comment: Okey, will do that in the future. I solved the problem. Apparently there is a max upload size on files for infinityfree.net of 10mb so that solved the problem. Thanks for your help.